# Getting rest id [...rest].js file from link like VehicleDetails/4

Tags: react-native, expo-router

I have a link when clicked takes a user to a specific page. In that page i would like to display specific data from the passed ID. My link looks like `VehicleDetails/4`

How can i get the id 4

I am using segments

```
const segmentPattern = /^VehicleDetails\/(\d+)$/; 
const match = segments[0].match(segmentPattern); 
const id = match ? match[1] : null; 

alert(id);
```

My code returns null.

but i cant get the rest id for instance in `VehicleDetails/4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used pathname and it worked

`onPress={() => { router.push({ pathname: 'VehicleDetails/[id]', params: { id: 4} }); }}`

then

`import { usePathname   } from "expo-router";`

```
const pathName = usePathname();
 const segments = pathName.split('/'); 
 const id = segments[2]; 
 
 alert(id);
```